# The left brace (\left{) is set in a different math version than the rest of the formula

Tags: versions

I just want to get only `$\left \{$` in "Spec math version", all inside and outside have to be back to "OK version". My attempt:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\DeclareMathVersion{OK}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{OK}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{OK}{OML}{cmbrm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{OK}{OMS}{cmbrs}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OK}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{it}
%--------------------------------------------------------
\DeclareMathVersion{Spec}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{Spec}{OMX}{cmbrs}{m}{it}
%--------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\va}[2]{\mathversion{Spec}\ensuremath{\left \{ \mathversion{OK} \begin{array}{l}
            {#1} \\
            {#2}
    \end{array}} \right.}
\begin{document}
    \mathversion{OK}
    \[\forall x,y: \va{x + y = 0}{x - y = 0} \Rightarrow x = y = 0 \]
\end{document}
```

The inner portion is corrected, but the outer portion still contains problematic formatting. I'm unsure how to properly fix it - could you please assist?

Comment: Try to move `\right.` inside of `\ensuremath`. So that `\left\{` and `\right.` are at the same level.

Comment: don't ignore warnings!!!!  `LaTeX Font Warning: Command \mathversion invalid in math mode on input line 18.`  you can not use `\mathversion` in this way.

Comment: You could declare a separate extension font in the OK mathversion and use that, but cmbright doesn't have an extension font with large brackets as far as I can see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't ignore warnings!!!!

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Command \mathversion invalid in math mode on input line 18.
```

you can not use `\mathversion` in this way.

You could declare a separate extension font in the OK mathversion and use that, but cmbright doesn't have an extension font with large brackets as far as I can see, this is using  computer modern `{`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\DeclareMathVersion{OK}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{OK}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{OK}{OML}{cmbrm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{OK}{OMS}{cmbrs}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OK}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}
%--------------------------------------------------------

\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsx}     {OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsx}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\xlb}
   {\mathopen}{symbolsx}{"66}{largesymbolsx}{"08}

%--------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\va}[2]{\left\xlb\begin{array}{l}
            {#1} \\
            {#2}
    \end{array} \right.}
\begin{document}
    \mathversion{OK}
    \[\forall x,y: \va{x + y = 0}{x - y = 0} \Rightarrow x = y = 0 \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Such a nice answer, hats off.

Comment: It's worked! Thank you very much. In addition, how do you now that are "66 and "08? I want to do the same with the bracket [. Could you please share?

Comment: the code shown is the definition of `\lbrace` just renamed the command and the font families, so look in latex/base/fontmath.ltx and copy whichever you need @ChauLong

Comment: I got it, now it's changed to fontdef.dtx, thank you very much!

Comment: @ChauLong fontdef.dtx is the documented source, fontmath.ltx is the file in the tex input tree that is used (but you can copy from either of course:-)

Comment: Oh. Where can find this file and what is the input tree?